# What does `dplyr:::bind_rows_` do?

Tags: r, function, dplyr

At the end of the function `dplyr::bind_rows`, the function `dplyr:::bind_rows_` is called. The full code of the this function is:

```
function (dots, id) 
{
    .Call(`_dplyr_bind_rows_`, dots, id)
}
```

What does this function do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It runs the C function `_dplyr_bind_rows_` with the arguments `dots` and `id`.

For more information about using `.Call` in R, see for example [these slides](http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/~bcaffo/statcomp/files/dotCall.pdf).